# Ordering database query - what to do when number of records increases?

Tags: database, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say I have an application where the user can attribute scores to movies, thus ranking them. Assume also that every time a user accesses this listing, the ranking must be updated. When there are only a few movies, it is certainly OK to do the query with an option to order the result by score.

However, when the number of movies is very high, it is reasonable to think that this query will take awfully long. What are the known techniques to help reduce this time? Should I perform a pre-ordering of the table itself from time to time?

I am using Ruby On Rails 3.1 for what it's worth...

Thanks

Comment: how bout some asynchronous calls to the db - seems a good fit for some AJAXing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create an [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) on movie score. This stores the order of records by score and automatically updates (pre-orders) when rankings are changed. When you select from the database ordering by score, the index will be used.